# Selenium-WebDriver opened the new Firefox window, but didn’t navigate to URL

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver

My source code is copied from selenium docs site. I didn’t make any change.
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms
I installed Selenium library via NuGet, including 
Selenium Remote Control(RC), Selenium WebDriver Mono, Selenium WebDriver Support Classes, Selenium WebDriver, and Selenium WebDriver-backed Selenium.

When I run this code, a new Firefox window was opened. But the Firefox doesn’t navigate to the URL, it just stuck, nothing was loaded.
I tried the Firefox v27, v29, v30 and v31, none of them worked.

[image]

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

// Requires reference to WebDriver.Support.dll
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

class GoogleSuggest
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver.

    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.

    // Further note that other drivers (InternetExplorerDriver,
    // ChromeDriver, etc.) will require further configuration 
    // before this example will work. See the wiki pages for the
    // individual drivers at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki
    // for further information.
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
    //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

    // Find the text input element by its name
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

    // Enter something to search for
    query.SendKeys("Cheese");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    query.Submit();

    // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
    // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("cheese"); });

    // Should see: "Cheese - Google Search"
    System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);

    //Close the browser
    driver.Quit();
}
}
```

Comment: Possibly a bug: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7532

Comment: Note that the current NuGet package is v2.42.0, support for Firefox 30 will be available in the next version ([source](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7488#c1)).

Comment: Thanks, it is a bug. I tested the different versions of Firefox.  The version 17, 24, 25 work fine. The version 27 ~ 31 don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. the solution is simply  uninstall your current firefox browser and download older version "i tried 2010 version 3.6.10 works great". your code is fine the problem is Mozilla people have decided to not give the right to any third party application to control Firefox.

good luck